# NodeJS how to install an app on my server to be served over url?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker

ok, this maybe a very rookie question but I'd like to install a application I found on [github precisely this one](https://github.com/cheeaun/puppetron)

my website say is `example.com`, and I want to be able to serve that app via url like

```
example.com/puppetron
```

I accessed via terminal my server (Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS) and I installed latest node js 7.x as required...

now i dont know how to proceed...
i placed the files in the folder

```
example.com/puppetron
```

and i did

```
pm2 start /var/www/example.com/puppetron/index.js
```

is this correct?? i have no idea what i'm doing...

please give me some guidance

Comment: That's enough to run it, but it will be accessible on http://example.com:3000/  Depending on what web server you use, you would need to forward/proxy requests for http://example.com/puppetron/* to the server running on 3000

Comment: Once you have figured out what web server (probably httpd or nginx) ask on https://serverfault.com if you need help with the config.